# How to make \n in java appear as a normal text?

Tags: java, string

As the title says, How to make `\n` in java appear as a normal text?

For example:

```
String example = "In Java, we use \n to make a new line.";
System.out.println(example);
```

The output is:

`In Java, we use 
 to make a new line.`

How can I make the output look the same as this:

`In Java, we use \n to make a new line.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use escape character `\`.

```
String example = "In Java, we use \\n to make a new line.";
```

See Java Documentation [§ Escape Sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) chapter for the detailed explanation and more examples.

Comment: `"In Java, we use \"\\n\" to make a new line."` could point out more clearly what in that sentence is Java `String` and what is just texutal explanation… Every backslash excapes the following character if it is one that manipulates `String`s

Answer (score 3):

Try to use a double backslash `\\n` like this:

```
String example = "In Java, we use \\n to make a new line.";
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape the `\` character using `\\`

```
String example = "In Java, we use \\n to make a new line.";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this  `\\n` instead of this `\n`

Comment: sorry bad answer format, edited right now